# JS: Regular expression for string

Tags: javascript, regex, date

i have js and a different strings like this:

```
Tue Aug 11 2015 between  4:00 PM and  5:00 PM
```

words `between` and `and` not changed 
But sometimes i can get this string with different amount of spaces between words

```
Tue Aug 11 2015 between   4:00 PM and   5:00 PM  (3 spaces)
```

or

```
Tue Aug 11 2015 between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM (1 spaces)
```

Is it possible to create a regular expression for this string?

```
  string re1="((?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Tues|Thur|Thurs|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat))";  // Day Of Week 1
  string re2="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
  string re3="((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))"; // Month 1
  string re4="(\\s+)";  // White Space 2
  string re5="((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])";  // Day 1
  string re6="(\\s+)";  // White Space 3
  string re7="((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])";    // Year 1
  string re8="(\\s+)";  // White Space 4
  string re9="(\"between\")";   // Double Quote String 1
  string re10="(\\s+)"; // White Space 5
  string re11="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"; // HourMinuteSec 1
  string re12="(\\s+)"; // White Space 6
  string re13="(\"and\")";  // Double Quote String 2
  string re14="(\\s+)"; // White Space 7
  string re15="((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"; // HourMinuteSec 2
```

how to simplify the regular expression for this line?

Comment: You could use `\s+` to denote one or more white space characters.

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to extract/replace?

Comment: For Day, `string re1 = "((?:Tues?|Thu(rs?)?|Sun|Mon|Wed|Fri|Sat))"; // Day Of Week 1`

Comment: You don't need different `regex` to match multiple spaces, `re4
re6
re8
re10
re12
re14` can be replaced by `re2`

Comment: Add complete code where you've used these regex patterns, so that the question will be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt to re-use your code:

```js
var re1="((?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Tues|Thur|Thurs|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat))";  // Day Of Week 1
var re2="\\s+";  // White Space 1
var re3="((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))"; // Month 1
var re5="((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d)|(?:3[01])))(?!\\d)";  // Day 1
var re7="(\\b(?:1\\d{3}|2\\d{3})\\b)";    // Year 1
var re11="((?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\\s*(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)"; // HourMinuteSec 
var reDay = "\\b((?:0?\\d|[12]\\d|3[01]))\\b";

var s = "Tue Aug 11 2015 between  4:00 PM and  5:00 PM";
var rx = RegExp(re1 + re2 + re3 + re2 + reDay + re2 + re7 + re2 + "between" + re2 + re11 + re2 + "and" + re2 + re11, 'i');
if ((m = rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
  document.write("Day of week: " + m[1] + "<br/>");
  document.write("Month: " + m[2] + "<br/>");
  document.write("Day: " + m[3] + "<br/>");
  document.write("Year: " + m[4] + "<br/>");
  document.write("From: " + m[5] + "<br/>");
  document.write("Till: " + m[6]);
  
}
```

Note that I am not capturing whitespace (removed parentheses), added a `reDay` for days that just captures two digits as a whole word with `\b\d{1,2}\b`, and I have leaned out some of your regexps (removed unnecessary brackets) and fixed the time regex by changing `\s?` to `\s*`. It looks like that was the main problem since `?` stands for *0 or 1 occurrence*, and `*` means *0 or more occurrences*.

Comment: You can also optimize the regex for day as you've done for month. To make some text optional

Comment: @Tushar: Do you mean *precise* the day regex? Like `var reDay = "\\b((?:0?\\d|[12]\\d|3[01]))\\b"`? I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
```

it will remove all your extra space and keep just 1 space each time. 
so if you have 3 spaces like you said it will convert it to 1 space

Comment: I doubt whitespace trimming and shrinking is what OP needs.

Comment: The question does not state what OP needs except the part this answer answers :).

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński i changed question - it is ok